# load image into imageview as a bitmap with Glide many time

Tags: android, bitmap, out-of-memory, android-glide

I want to create an app like Instagram. My users can select their own images from their storage, crop them and send them to server. I have a fragment with an `CropperImageView` in top and a `RecyclerView` in the bottom. I used [this library](https://github.com/jayrambhia/CropperNoCropper) for image cropping. When user clicks on an image in `RecyclerView`, I load that image as a bitmap and set that bitmap for `CropperImageView` like the following

```
 Glide.with(getContext()).asBitmap().load(imageFilePath).into(new SimpleTarget<Bitmap>() {
            @Override
            public void onResourceReady(@NonNull Bitmap resource, @Nullable Transition<? super Bitmap> transition) {
                cropperView.setImageBitmap(resource);
            }
        });
```

Because a user can click on Recyclerview image items many times. I get `OutOfMemory` exception from Glide. the following is Glide log in logcat.

```
W/Glide: Load failed for /storage/4BC8-1B11/DCIM/Camera/20180520_210400.jpg with size [-2147483648x-2147483648]
                                                        class com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.GlideException: Failed to load resource
                                                        There was 1 cause:
                                                        java.lang.OutOfMemoryError(Failed to allocate a 51121164 byte allocation with 16701336 free bytes and 15MB until OOM)
                                                         call GlideException#logRootCauses(String) for more detail
                                                          Cause (1 of 3): class com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.GlideException: Failed LoadPath{FileInputStream->Bitmap->Bitmap}, LOCAL
                                                        There was 1 cause:
                                                        java.lang.OutOfMemoryError(Failed to allocate a 51121164 byte allocation with 16701336 free bytes and 15MB until OOM)
                                                         call GlideException#logRootCauses(String) for more detail
                                                            Cause (1 of 1): class com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.GlideException: Failed DecodePath{FileInputStream->Bitmap->Bitmap}
                                                        There was 1 cause:
                                                        java.lang.OutOfMemoryError(Failed to allocate a 51121164 byte allocation with 16701336 free bytes and 15MB until OOM)
                                                         call GlideException#logRootCauses(String) for more detail
                                                              Cause (1 of 1): class java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Failed to allocate a 51121164 byte allocation with 16701336 free bytes and 15MB until OOM
                                                          Cause (2 of 3): class com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.GlideException: Failed LoadPath{ParcelFileDescriptor->Bitmap->Bitmap}, LOCAL
                                                            Cause (1 of 1): class com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.GlideException: Failed DecodePath{ParcelFileDescriptor->Bitmap->Bitmap}
                                                          Cause (3 of 3): class com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.GlideException: Failed LoadPath{AssetFileDescriptor->Bitmap->Bitmap}, LOCAL
                                                            Cause (1 of 1): class com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.GlideException: Failed DecodePath{AssetFileDescriptor->Bitmap->Bitmap}
05-21 14:09:34.140 13837-13837/com.mediana.vip I/Glide: Root cause (1 of 1)
                                                        java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Failed to allocate a 51121164 byte allocation with 16701336 free bytes and 15MB until OOM
                                                            at dalvik.system.VMRuntime.newNonMovableArray(Native Method)
                                                            at android.graphics.Bitmap.nativeCreate(Native Method)
                                                            at android.graphics.Bitmap.createBitmap(Bitmap.java:977)
                                                            at android.graphics.Bitmap.createBitmap(Bitmap.java:948)
                                                            at android.graphics.Bitmap.createBitmap(Bitmap.java:915)
                                                            at com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.bitmap_recycle.LruBitmapPool.createBitmap(LruBitmapPool.java:149)
                                                            at com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.bitmap_recycle.LruBitmapPool.get(LruBitmapPool.java:131)
                                                            at com.bumptech.glide.load.resource.bitmap.TransformationUtils.rotateImageExif(TransformationUtils.java:329)
                                                            at com.bumptech.glide.load.resource.bitmap.Downsampler.decodeFromWrappedStreams(Downsampler.java:314)
                                                            at com.bumptech.glide.load.resource.bitmap.Downsampler.decode(Downsampler.java:207)
                                                            at com.bumptech.glide.load.resource.bitmap.StreamBitmapDecoder.decode(StreamBitmapDecoder.java:62)
                                                            at com.bumptech.glide.load.resource.bitmap.StreamBitmapDecoder.decode(StreamBitmapDecoder.java:18)
                                                            at com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.DecodePath.decodeResourceWithList(DecodePath.java:72)
                                                            at com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.DecodePath.decodeResource(DecodePath.java:55)
                                                            at com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.DecodePath.decode(DecodePath.java:45)
                                                            at com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.LoadPath.loadWithExceptionList(LoadPath.java:58)
                                                            at com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.LoadPath.load(LoadPath.java:43)
                                                            at com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.DecodeJob.runLoadPath(DecodeJob.java:498)
                                                            at com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.DecodeJob.decodeFromFetcher(DecodeJob.java:469)
                                                            at com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.DecodeJob.decodeFromData(DecodeJob.java:455)
                                                            at com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.DecodeJob.decodeFromRetrievedData(DecodeJob.java:407)
                                                            at com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.DecodeJob.onDataFetcherReady(DecodeJob.java:376)
                                                            at com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.SourceGenerator.onDataReady(SourceGenerator.java:112)
                                                            at com.bumptech.glide.load.model.MultiModelLoader$MultiFetcher.onDataReady(MultiModelLoader.java:133)
                                                            at com.bumptech.glide.load.data.LocalUriFetcher.loadData(LocalUriFetcher.java:52)
                                                            at com.bumptech.glide.load.model.MultiModelLoader$MultiFetcher.loadData(MultiModelLoader.java:97)
                                                            at com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.SourceGenerator.startNext(SourceGenerator.java:62)
                                                            at com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.DecodeJob.runGenerators(DecodeJob.java:299)
                                                            at com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.DecodeJob.runWrapped(DecodeJob.java:269)
                                                            at com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.DecodeJob.run(DecodeJob.java:230)
                                                            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1133)
                                                            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:607)
                                                            at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:762)
                                                            at com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.executor.GlideExecutor$DefaultThreadFactory$1.run(GlideExecutor.java:446)
```

How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

I solved my problem with setting width and height for `SimpleTarge`. Because I didn't set width and height for `SimpleTarget`, It considered the original size of image. When I changed the code as following, I didn't get OutOfMemory exception from Glide.

```
Glide.with(getContext()).asBitmap().load(imageFilePath).into(new SimpleTarget<Bitmap>(cropperView.getWidth(),cropperView.getHeight()) {
        @Override
        public void onResourceReady(@NonNull Bitmap resource, @Nullable Transition<? super Bitmap> transition) {
            cropperView.setImageBitmap(resource);
        }
    });
```